# Calling the home controller action using ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an 'Index' action within my home controller which responds to the url '/'. The action also has an optional 'id' parameter...

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResultBase Index(int id = -1)
{
     ....
}
```

the routing for this is...

```
routes.MapRoute("Home",
                "",
                 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = -1 } );
```

If I try to call this action using ajax...

```
    $.get(
        '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
        { id: 20 },
        function (response) {
        });
```

the call fails as the url is /?id=20

Is it possible to force the Url.Action to include the controller and action names, as when I do this...

'@Url.Action("Index", "Home")' + 'Home/Index'

all works fine, or do I need to correct my routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to make a special route for your Action method like so. The default route:

```
 {controller}/{action}/{id}, 
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Handles that case already; when you request '/' on your server, you should get sent to your `Home/Index` action method. You should remove the custom route you have specified and let the default route send you to the correct destination.